# CAN Split Termination Capacitor Calculation

Tags: filter, differential, can, low-pass, termination

I'm trying to use the split termination on a CAN bus, but I'm a bit confused about the calculation for the split termination capacitor. It is described in Figure 10 in the Texas Instruments app note [SLLA270 Controller Area Network Physical Requirements](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla270/slla270.pdf?ts=1595886457878&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) but when I use the values of R = 60 Ohms and C = 4.7nF, I geta cutoff frequency of 564.379 kbps and not 1.1 Mbps like they describe in the app note.
[image]

I'm confused as to how they got 1.1 Mbps and why ? Isn't the RC low pass filter here created by the resistor and capacitor (60 ohms and 4.7 nF) ?

Answer (score 5):

60 Ohm in parallel with 60 Ohm is 30 Ohm.
RC-Filter with 30 Ohm and 4,7nF has 1.1MHz corner frequency.

Comment: Somewhat more detail re the 60//60 effect would be helpful. It's obvious once you see it but can be unclear otherwise.

Comment: Could you explain a little more why they go in parallel ? And if the resistors go in parallel why don't the capacitors ?

Answer (score 1):

In the worst case scenario, a CAN message will contain alternating bits (...01010101...), which will produce a square wave with a fundamental frequency of HALF the baud rate:

[image: baud rate vs fundamental frequency]

This ignores the higher harmonics to produce a clean square wave, however.

See this post about CAN circuitry: https://resources.altium.com/p/can-bus-designing-can-bus-circuitry

> In my case, the network should have a 1mbit/s baud rate. Assuming the worst-case scenario, when the network is transmitting a sequence of alternating bits (01010101) the signal will be a square wave of frequency 500kHz, or equal to half the baud rate.
> We know the resistance at 60 ohms, we can thus calculate the capacitor.
> [image]

This post seems to suggest that it's not actually important to place the cut-off frequency above the baud rate anyway: https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/industrial_strength/posts/the-importance-of-termination-networks-in-can-transceivers

> Typical concerns I have heard with this termination technique include, “Will this filter my CAN bus signals?” and “Do I need to place the corner frequency above my data rate?” The simple answer to both questions is no. Since the capacitor does not place a direct current (DC) load on the differential bus signal – it only filters the alternating current (AC) signal and the common-mode signal – and the differential signal is what determines the bus state, you do not need to set the corner frequency of the filter above the data rate.